# How can i merge 2 arrays with a condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two arrays:

```
workers:  [
{name: Jonh, id: 1}, 
{name: Mixel, id: 2},
{name: Carl, id: 3}
]

diseases:  [
{diseaseID: 50, name: Jonh, diseaseName: Cancer},
{diseaseID: 60, name: Jonh,  diseaseName: Lupus },
{diseaseID: 70, name: Carl,  diseaseName: BrainShok}
]
```

and what i need is making a new a array mergin some elements of the both array, when the names are the same, for example:

```
workers.forEach(data => {
    this.theNewArray.push({
     "newName" = data.name
     "newID"= data.diseaseID
     "newdiseaseID" = "??????????????(here is the problem, idk how to make a push of the disease everytime when the name are the same)

  })
})
```

And in the very end, when the forEach end, the array should be something like this:

```
this.theNewArray = [
 {  "NewName": "Jonh",  "newID": "1",  "newdiseaseID" = [
    {"diseaseID": '50', "diseaseName": 'Cancer'},  
    {"diseaseID": '60', "diseaseName": 'Lupus '}
]},

 {  "NewName": "Mixel",  "newID": "2",  "newdiseaseID" = []},
 {  "NewName": "Carl",  "newID": "3",  "newdiseaseID" = [{"diseaseID": '70', "diseaseName": 'BrainShok'}]}
]
```

How can i do this? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). No need for looping.

```js
const workers = [
  {name: 'Jonh', id: 1}, 
  {name: 'Mixel', id: 2},
  {name: 'Carl', id: 3}
];

const diseases = [
  {diseaseID: 50, name: 'Jonh', diseaseName: 'Cancer'},
  {diseaseID: 60, name: 'Jonh',  diseaseName: 'Lupus'},
  {diseaseID: 70, name: 'Carl',  diseaseName: 'BrainShok'}
];


const newArray = workers.map((worker) => (
  {
    newName: worker.name, 
    newId: worker.id,
    newDiseaseId: diseases.filter(disease => disease.name === worker.name).map(({ diseaseID, diseaseName }) => ({ diseaseID, diseaseName }))
  }
));

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: its working but i need the "newDiseaseId" have this format:
[
 {  "NewName": "Jonh",  "newID": "1",  "newdiseaseID" = [
    {"diseaseID": '50', "diseaseName": 'Cancer'},  
    {"diseaseID": '60', "diseaseName": 'Lupus '}
]}

Comment: Jacob edited this answer for you. It should be returning that now.